# Programmatically click button in child component form

Tags: angular

I'm trying to click a button on a form inside a child component. I've  tried using `ViewChild` & `ViewChildren` also, referencing the template ref as `ElementRef`. It all returns the values and not the native elements. [stackblitz-demo](https://angular-rdapzg.stackblitz.io)

```js
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  AfterViewInit,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HelloComponent
} from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('test') form: ElementRef;
  name = 'Angular';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }
}



import {
  Component,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  Child Component
    <form class="login-as-user" [action]="formUrl" method="post" target="_blank">
      <input id="login-as-user" type="submit" value="reference this button">
    </form>
`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Comment: It should have a `nativeElement` property

Comment: @user184994 it returns undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is this:
`@ViewChild('test', {read: ElementRef}) form: ElementRef;`

For more information please read the following article:

[Angular @ViewChild: How to read multiple tokens](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-viewchild-how-to-read-multiple-instances-cde38ef19041)

Comment: you know where to find more on this `{read: ElementRef}`, like docs?

Comment: This work for me, I does not understand why is this complicated...

Answer (score 5):

You can add a function in the child component that in fact clicks programmatically on it's own button by using `ViewChild` of the desired button, then accessing `nativeElement.click()`.

Then trigger that function from the parent component with another `ViewChild` for the child component

Child :

- Template : `<input id="login-as-user #buttomToBeClicked>`
- TS: `@ViewChild('buttonToBeClicked') buttonToBeClicked: ElementRef;`

Then add the click function:

```
clickButton(){
  this.buttonToBeClicked.nativeElement.click();
}
```

Parent :

- Template : `<hello #child></hello>`
- TS: `@ViewChild('child') child;`

Then call the click function in your parent component like this:

```
this.child.clickButton();
```

**Edit:**

You can just do `this.child.buttonToBeClicked.nativeElement.click();` as a shortcut, but communication through an extra method gives you more flexibility to add any checks in your child component